# Blender CUDA Flatpack

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

OS: Manjaro KDE
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1650

I tried using blender from the official repos, for some reason certain features dint work.
I installed blender from Flatpak, everything works fine exept it does not detect my GPU,

But CUDA worked fine when I used it from official repos,

Does anyone have a fix for this?

I have tried reinstalling, It dint work!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install NVIDIA drivers separately via flatpak to enable GPU rendering.

- Run  `flatpak list`  in console.
- Check if you have a package with application id similar to

  ```
  org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia
  ```
- If not run  `flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia` 
  and install the latest drivers.At the time of writing this the latest driver was org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-27-04